# 404 error in moving Magento 2

Tags: magento2, configuration, migration, 404-page

Moving Magento2 from one sub-folder to another sub-folder in same domain displaying 404 error everywhere except home-page. Admin is also displaying 404 error.

Steps to produce:

1. Copy all files from one folder to another-folder
2. Created new db and imported from current db
3. Updated database details in new `sub-folder/app/etc/env.php` (Only database name is changed).
4. Modify the value of `web/unsecure/base_url` and `web/secure/base_url` in `core_config_data` table
5. Clear cache and also tried to changed mode from production to developer and vica versa.

Magento version: 2.1.3

Comment: You need to deploy static content

Comment: Require to `update` Magento path where you create domain. now your site get old Magento folder path.

Answer (score 0):

Use steps, I think it will help you.

1. pub/static/ remove all files except `.htaccess`
2. var/cache/ remove all files
3. Run setup upgrade command
4. Change pub & var permission 777
5. Run `sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`
6. Run cache clear & flush commands
7. Change pub & var permission 777